# Двумерные массивы(матрицы)

Tags: javascript

Существует ли возможность объявлять в javascript двумерные массивы кроме варианта:

```
mass=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Т.е. если в функцию передаётся размерность массива, а функция формирует массив с указанной размерностью?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Разумеется.

```
function matrixArray(rows,columns){
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
    arr[i] = new Array();
    for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
      arr[i][j] = i+j+1;//вместо i+j+1 пишем любой наполнитель. В простейшем случае - null
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
var myMatrix = matrixArray(3,3);
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, мне нравится и я им уже воспользовался. Раньше у меня были проблемы с объявлением двумерных массивов:) Добавлю я это в закладки:)

Comment: во имя Крокфорда - вместо `new Array()` используйте `[]`